# Devexpress combo: Can't set SelectedIndex higher than 99 on clientside

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I use a performCallback to add a new item to my ASPxCombo on serverside, and want to change my index to that new item on the client side. I use DevExpress onEndCallback to do this and it is working great if my index is <= 99. Above that the index is not changed.

Do anybody no if DevExpress's SetSelectedIndex() method works with index greater than this, seems a little strange to me.

```
                <dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" 
                                ID="CmbManufacturer" 
                                ClientInstanceName="cmbManufacturer"
                                CssClass="dxeButtonEdit_LWDisplayEdit_CustomDropDown" 

                                DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
                                EnableCallbackMode="True"
                                OnCallback="CmbManufacturer_Callback" 
                                ValueType="System.String"
                                FieldName="ID" 
                                TextFormatString="{0}" 
                                FilterBy="Name" 
                                TextField="Name" 
                                ValueField="ID"
                                EnableSynchronization="False" 
                                AllowEdit="false" 
                                ValidationSettings-Display="None"
                                AutoPostBack="False" 
                                Visible="False"
                                Width="400" >
                    <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s,e) {OnManufacturerChanged(s,e); }"
                        Init="function(s,e) {LwValidating2(s,e);}" 
                        EndCallback="function(s,e) { OnEndCallbackCmbManufacturer(s,e); }"/>
                </dx:ASPxComboBox>   


        function OnEndCallbackCmbManufacturer(s, e) {
        var index = s.cpSelectedIndex;
        s.SetSelectedIndex(index);
        OnManufacturerChanged(s, e);
    }
```

Comment: I have located the problem, but not solved it.The selectedIndex method can only change index according to callbackpagesize. If callback pagesize is ex. 5000 my code will work. but that is not practical. Anybody know how i can change or retrigger combo so it will go to the riht page in combo?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by moving my new Item in dropdownItemList up in front of list below CallbackpageSize. Then i can change index on combo to the Items new index.

```
        protected void CmbManufacturer_Callback(object source, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        var manufacturerName = e.Parameter.Trim();

        // need to move item to top of list because it must be lower than CallbackPagesize to work
        int indexforNewItem = 1;
            try
            {

                int newManufacturerId = SoftwareManufacturer.Update(-1, manufacturerName, "");
                LoadDropDownBoxManufacturer(null);
                int newManufacturerIndex = CmbManufacturer.Items.IndexOfText(manufacturerName);
                CmbManufacturer.Items.Move(newManufacturerIndex, indexforNewItem);
                CmbManufacturer.JSProperties["cpSelectedIndex"] = indexforNewItem;
            }

            catch ()
            {
            }
    }
```